# Extracting 1D ellipse from 2D image

Tags: python

I've trying to simulate a 2D [Sérsic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sersic_profile) profile and then testing an extraction routine on it. However, when I do a test by extracting all the points lying along an ellipse supposedly aligned with an image, I get a periodic function. It is meant to be a straight line since all points along the ellipse should have equal intensity, although there will be a small amount of deviation due to rounding errors in the rough coordinate estimation (`get_I()`).

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import NearestNDInterpolator

def rotate(x, y, angle):
    x1 = x*np.cos(angle) + y*np.sin(angle)
    y1 = y*np.cos(angle) - x*np.sin(angle)
    return x1, y1

def sersic_1d(R, mu0, h, n, zp=0):
    exponent = (R / h) **  (1 / n)
    I0 = np.exp((zp - mu0) / 2.5)
    return I0 * np.exp(-1.* exponent)

def sersic_2d(x, y, e, i, mu0, h, n, zp=0):
    xp, yp = rotate(x, y, i)
    alpha = np.arctan2(yp, xp * (1-e))
    a = xp / np.cos(alpha)
    b = a * (1 - e)
    # R2 = (a*a) + ((1 - (e*e)) * yp*yp)
    return sersic_1d(a, mu0, h, n, zp)


def ellipse(x0, y0, a, e, i, theta):
    b = a * (1 - e)
    x = a * np.cos(theta)
    y = b * np.sin(theta)
    x, y = rotate(x, y, i)
    return x + x0, y + y0   

def get_I(x, y, Z):
    return Z[np.round(x).astype(int), np.round(y).astype(int)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = np.linspace(-100,100,1000)
    nx, ny = np.meshgrid(n, n)
    Z = sersic_2d(nx, ny, 0.5, 0., 0, 50, 1, 25)

    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000.)
    a = 100.
    e = 0.5
    i = np.pi / 4.
    x, y = ellipse(0, 0, a, e, i, theta)
    I = get_I(x, y, Z)
    plt.plot(I)
    # plt.imshow(Z)
    plt.show()
```

However, What I actually get is a massive periodic function. [image: wrong extraction] I've checked the alignment and it's correct and the float-> int rounding errors can't account for this kind of shift?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that strike me as odd, one of which for sure is not what you wanted, the other I'm not sure about because astronomy is not my field of expertise.

The first is in your function `get_I`:

```
def get_I(x, y, Z):
    return Z[np.round(x).astype(int), np.round(y).astype(int)]
```

When you call that function, `x` an `y` outline an ellipse, with its center at the origin `(0,0)`. That means `x` and `y` both become negative at some point. The indexing you perfom in that function will then take values from the array's last elements, because `Z[0,0]` is in fact the top left corner of the image (which you plotted, but commented), while `Z[-1, -1]` is the bottom right corner. What you want is to take the values of `Z` that are on the ellipse contour, but both have to have the same center. To do that, you would first make sure you use an *uneven* amount of samples for `n` (which ultimately defines the `shape` of `Z`) and second, you would *add an indexing offset*:

```
def get_I(x, y, Z):
    offset = Z.shape[0]//2
    return Z[np.round(y).astype(int) + offset, np.round(x).astype(int) + offset]

...
n = np.linspace(-100,100,1001) # changed from 1000 to 1001 to ensure a point of origin is present and that the image exhibits point symmetry
```

Also notice that I changed the order of `y` and `x` in `get_I`: that's because you first index along the rows (for which we usually take the y-coordinate) and only then along the columns (which map to the x-coordinate in most conventions).

The second item that struck me as unusual is that your ellipse has its axes at an angle of `pi/4` with respect to the horizontal axis, whereas your `sersic` (which maps to the 2D array of `Z`) does not have a tilt at all.

---

Changing all that, I end up with this code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rotate(x, y, angle):
    x1 = x*np.cos(angle) + y*np.sin(angle)
    y1 = y*np.cos(angle) - x*np.sin(angle)
    return x1, y1

def sersic_1d(R, mu0, h, n, zp=0):
    exponent = (R / h) **  (1 / n)
    I0 = np.exp((zp - mu0) / 2.5)
    return I0 * np.exp(-1.* exponent)

def sersic_2d(x, y, e, ang, mu0, h, n, zp=0):
    xp, yp = rotate(x, y, ang)
    alpha = np.arctan2(yp, xp * (1-e))
    a = xp / np.cos(alpha)
    b = a * (1 - e)
    return sersic_1d(a, mu0, h, n, zp)

def ellipse(x0, y0, a, e, i, theta):
    b = a * (1 - e)  # half of a
    x = a * np.cos(theta)
    y = b * np.sin(theta)
    x, y = rotate(x, y, i)  # rotated by 45deg
    return x + x0, y + y0

def get_I(x, y, Z):
    offset = Z.shape[0]//2
    return Z[np.round(y).astype(int) + offset, np.round(x).astype(int) + offset]
    #return Z[np.round(y).astype(int), np.round(x).astype(int)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = np.linspace(-100,100,1001)  # changed
    nx, ny = np.meshgrid(n, n)
    ang = 0;#np.pi / 4.
    Z = sersic_2d(nx, ny, 0.5, ang=0, mu0=0, h=50, n=1, zp=25)
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
    dn = n[1]-n[0]
    ax[0].imshow(Z, cmap='gray', aspect='equal', extent=[-100-dn/2, 100+dn/2, -100-dn/2, 100+dn/2])
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000.)
    a = 20.  # decreased long axis of ellipse to see the intensity-map closer to the "center of the galaxy"
    e = 0.5
    x, y = ellipse(0,0, a, e, ang, theta)
    I = get_I(x, y, Z)
    ax[0].plot(x,y)  # easier to see where you want the intensities
    ax[1].plot(I)
    plt.show()
```

and this image:

[image: ellipse extracted from Sersic profile]

The intensity variations look like quantisation noise to me, with the exception of the peaks, which are due to the asymptote in `sersic_1d`.

Comment: Thanks. I just finished making most of those corrections myself. I've also found that RectBivariateSpline works well to get rid of the quantisation errors!